# Django deltatime formatting

Tags: python, django

I'm just wondering what the best way is to get this:

```
0:01:23.415000
```

To look like this:

```
1 minute, 23 seconds
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime ?

Comment: I'm simply looking for formatting, because it a duration. That seems to be a relative time from the current time. But that is also good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solvable by a few simple string methods (assuming your input is indeed a string).

```
td = "0:01:23.415000"
time = td.split(':')
time_string = ''
if int(time[0]):
    time_string += time[0]
    if int(time[0]) > 1:
        time_string += " hours, "
    else:
        time_string += " hour, "
if int(time[1]):
    time_string += str(time[1])
    if int(time[1]) > 1:
        time_string += " minute, "
    else:
        time_string += " minutes, "
if float(time[2]):
    time_string += str(int(float(time[3])))
    if int(float(time[2])) > 1:
        time_string += " second"
    else:
        time_string += " seconds"
print time_string
```

This is mindful of plurality of units, and rounding on the seconds.  There is probably a more concise way to write this, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Check the django docs, though.  If timedelta is a Django object, there's probably a much simpler built-in method for this.

Comment: I've looked everywhere. There's a lot of formatting for dates, but not times. I guess I'll have to write a custom filter and employ something like your solution.